My pre-processed MRIs are awfully bright, even after intensity normalization
First question - I'm working with the ADNI MRI dataset, which you have to apply to get access to. I'm aware I can't share the data, but am I allowed to post a few pre-processed MRIs (only, without the metadata)? What about derivatives (a histogram of the pixel intensities of an MRI)?
Next, I followed the preprocessing steps described in this repo, which can be summarized as re-orientation, cropping, skull-stripping, linear registration, segmentation & bias correction, and centering. However my resulting images are horrible. One of the issues is that my images are awfully bright. I have plotted the histogram (not included yet in this post) of the pixel intensities, and there is a very huge spike at the value 1 (pure white). I have a few example images of a well-processed MRI images, and the pixel intensity histogram should looks like this (0 is pure black, 255 is pure white):

All of my pre-processing was done with FSL. Could you point out to me what could've possibly went wrong with my pre-processing?

"am I allowed to post a few pre-processed MRIs (only, without the metadata)? What about derivatives (a histogram of the pixel intensities of an MRI)?" - you need to read the license you agreed to when you were given access to the data.
